# Encryption using HTML

Tags: hash, html

How to encrypt password from the client side using HTML so as to prevent man in the middle attack.

I have tried the following:encrypt="sha1"

and it doesn't seem to work.

Is there any other way of encrypting using HTML

Comment: SHA-1 isn't an encryption algorithm. Also, HTML is a markup language, you cannot make algorithms with it, even less encrypt. Maybe you should start by learning the trade? You can easily find lots of books or teachers for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non SSL/TLS web page form for passwords? Security concerns?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/160222/non-ssl-tls-web-page-form-for-passwords-security-concerns)

Comment: Just use https/ssl/tls and forget about client side encryption/hashing.

Answer (score 7):

You can't do this with HTML alone. If you would want to hash passwords client-sided in a web application, you would have to implement the hashing algorithm in JavaScript.

But you don't want to do this, because it wouldn't be secure. An eavesdropper could just intercept the hash and then use that hash to impersonate the user without actually knowing their real password. An active man-in-the-middle attacker capable of modifying traffic could even modify your HTML document to arrive at the user with the encryption disabled, so they send the cleartext password.

But there is a much easier, more secure and less error-prone solution to your problem: **just enable https**. [It's free and simple](https://letsencrypt.org/) now.

Comment: It is possible to implement public-key crypto in Javascript.  Public key is embedded in the Javascript, password encrypted into blob at the client, only can be decrypted at the server.  But, as you say, HTTPS is easier, more secure, and less error-prone.